# Gradle Error trying build an Cordova application with ionic

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I can't build my Ionic project, when I run `ionic cordova build android` it happens:

```
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :CordovaLib) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=22, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /home/terry/Documentos/Viitra/app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/debug/classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
           The dependency contains Java 8 bytecode. Please enable desugaring by adding the following to build.gradle
           android {
               compileOptions {
                   sourceCompatibility 1.8
                   targetCompatibility 1.8
               }
           }
           See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html for details. Alternatively, increase the minSdkVersion to 26 or above.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Already tried that solution to add java-8 support but it is already exists all my build.gradle files:

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

There is my lib's versions:

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.29
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
@angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : not available
Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.8.1
native-run (update available: 1.3.0)   : 0.3.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/terry/Android/Sdk)
NodeJS            : v12.19.0 (/var/lib/snapd/snap/node/3292/bin/node)
npm               : 6.14.8
OS                : Linux 5.10

***Edit:
Fixed changing the package.json file, downgrading Cordova-Android version.***

Comment: open this app in android studio and run `gradle`

Comment: Ok, i'll try and add the output to the post